# Finding controls in gridview? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web applicatiom i am trying to find grid controls in RowDataBound event. But it is giving object reference to instance of an object, this is my code :

```
     protected void mygrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
          {

                 string empid = "";         

                 empid = ((Label)e.Row .FindControl("lblname")).Text;
           }
```

Can you hlep me please to find the control, thank you.

Comment: try this `Label lblprop_img_id = (Label)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblprop_img_id");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya, i got the answer, i have to place

```
        string empid = "";
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
        {
            empid = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblname")).Text;
        }
```

then i we get the control

Answer (score 1):

Find control for Data rows only Like:

```
protected void mygrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
           string empid = "";         

           empid = ((Label)e.Row .FindControl("lblname")).Text;
       }
 }
```

Comment: ya thank you, pankaj, i got it that, i posted my answer, thank you for reply

Answer (score 1):

The "Object reference to instance of an object" error is probably because no control named lblname was found for the current row.

Maybe you need to check the type of the row, e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow so that you are not searching for the control in the header row.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblCreatedBy");
             lbl.Text = "ABC";
```